# About using Face API in C# project

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I used this project from  github:
https://github.com/jernejk/RealTimeFaceApi
, but the result always show "Getting identity failed."

My key and endpoint is correct, but I'm not sure the value of "FaceGroupId" is meaning persongroupId?(I use personGroupId here.)

I want to know whether the mistake exist in previous steps?

The following code show the 3 place need user to change:

```
public static class Program
    {
        // TODO: Add Face API subscription key.
        private static string FaceSubscriptionKey = "myFaceAPIkey";

        // TODO: Add face group ID.
        private static string FaceGroupId = "XXX";//I use persongroupId here.

        private static readonly Scalar _faceColorBrush = new Scalar(0, 0, 255);
        private static FaceClient _faceClient;
        private static Task _faceRecognitionTask = null;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _faceClient = new FaceClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(FaceSubscriptionKey))
            {
                Endpoint = "https://myendpoint.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0"
            };

            string filename = args.FirstOrDefault();
            Run(filename);
        }
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Sorry I repost again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run that project on my side successfully. Yes, the `FaceGroupId` should be the `persongroupId` that you created in your face API service. And the reason that you get error : `Getting identity failed.` is there is something wrong with your `Endpoint`  value in `_faceClient` , The value here should be :

```
https://<yourEndpoint>.cognitiveservices.azure.com
```

Will be ok. There is one thing that you should know if you use recognition model 02 to create and train your person groups, pls modify the code in `Program.cs` from:

```
var detectedFaces = await _faceClient.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(stream, true, true);
```

to :

```
var detectedFaces = await _faceClient.Face.DetectWithStreamAsync(stream,true,true,null, "recognition_02");
```

If you are using recognition model 01 , there is no need to change(I use 02 model on my side).

Result of that code here :
[image]

Hope it helps .

Comment: Hi @Hsuan Chou , may I know is it helpful ?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: But I have another question on DetectWithStreamAsync with  02 model ,because use "recognition_02" on argument it has some problem like "CS1503 C# Argument 6: cannot convert from 'string' to".